Multicolumn listings
Update
Changed the mwe to make the 2nd page larger and obviously 2 column.
Original
In using multicol for program listings with very short lines, I get page breaks where it should at most make column breaks.
Can someone please help me debug?
Pages as follows.
It's not quite visibly obvious but the 1st page has content only in the left column with the right column completely blank!
Page1

Page 2

The tex file:
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage[shortlabels, inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.95}
\definecolor{LightPGray}{gray}{0.90}
\lstnewenvironment{PYT}
      {\lstset{language=Python,
       backgroundcolor=\color{LightPGray},
       %basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
        basicstyle=\footnotesize,
        %flexiblecolumns=true,
        frame=single,
        basewidth={0.5em,0.45em},
    }}{}



\date{}
\begin{document}

\section{Section Lorem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{PYT}
>>> 1 + 2 
3
>>> () 
()
>>>(1,)
(1,)
>>> 1, 
(1,)
>>> (1,2) # Normal use
(1, 2)
>>> 1,2,  # Redundancy
(1, 2)
>>> []  # By contrast  
[]
>>> [1]
[1]
>>> [1,2]
[1, 2]
>>> [1,2]
[1,2]
1
\end{PYT}
\end{multicols}
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 

 Mauris nec dictum massa. Etiam et turpis quis dolor aliquam suscipit. Donec augue erat, interdum eget mi at, bibendum fermentum mauris. Proin ultrices risus a nulla luctus, vitae tincidunt nulla finibus. Pellentesque eget posuere mauris, sed malesuada dui. Aenean augue velit, ullamcorper vitae diam eu, rhoncus iaculis nisi. Nullam lorem velit, ullamcorper a dictum eget, fringilla ut turpis. Fusce maximus convallis consectetur. Fusce accumsan scelerisque odio, sed eleifend ex vulputate quis. Aliquam convallis non mauris non fringilla. Nulla iaculis, ipsum nec fermentum laoreet, nisi dolor lacinia turpis, sed tincidunt dui libero ac lorem. Nunc molestie felis at ullamcorper gravida. Donec elementum iaculis risus bibendum varius. Aliquam molestie, est et rutrum cursus, lacus lacus pulvinar lorem, nec dictum nulla lorem non nisl. Mauris ac tempus ex. Ut aliquet placerat dapibus.

Vestibulum tempor ultrices purus, vitae ultrices ipsum cursus a. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam non orci quis ipsum rhoncus hendrerit. Praesent sit amet ipsum eget odio vulputate tempus nec ac lacus. Nunc sit amet diam ac ipsum dignissim efficitur ac nec mauris. Donec tempor quam enim, a sollicitudin massa vulputate ut. Suspendisse faucibus mi consectetur aliquet elementum. Mauris purus mauris, lacinia vel vestibulum a, scelerisque bibendum libero. Donec congue tortor at convallis ornare. Donec sit amet vulputate nisl, non mattis sapien. Nunc venenatis ipsum ut magna fermentum sagittis.

Sed in velit vitae metus pulvinar tristique nec sed sem. Quisque semper arcu eget lectus convallis, a tempor felis fringilla. Mauris at velit orci. Aenean dui tortor, tincidunt quis volutpat non, accumsan in dui. Fusce condimentum viverra gravida. Nam ligula lacus, egestas sit amet commodo eu, tempor vel mi. Suspendisse fringilla ornare metus at mattis. Etiam in porta dolor. Pellentesque non ultrices est. Quisque tincidunt at lectus quis vulputate. In vitae metus eu metus sodales venenatis a sed neque. Pellentesque sed turpis ut mi luctus convallis. In a eleifend tortor, vel dignissim diam. Curabitur facilisis sapien et tincidunt vehicula. Aliquam fermentum leo vitae ullamcorper sodales.

Suspendisse eu lobortis urna, auctor aliquet orci. Praesent vitae dolor accumsan, maximus urna non, pulvinar risus. Ut dignissim nisi non suscipit commodo. Vestibulum finibus metus sem, nec placerat eros ullamcorper ac. Morbi congue, leo vel laoreet pharetra, lacus lorem condimentum odio, eu sagittis metus leo sed dolor. Duis ut magna non massa accumsan accumsan vitae vestibulum mi. Aenean dignissim urna sed dapibus fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Etiam suscipit, tellus ut finibus fermentum, sapien augue malesuada urna, ut aliquet quam quam vitae velit. Aliquam et sem quam.

Suspendisse tempus bibendum viverra. In lorem mauris, pulvinar nec tellus eu, cursus finibus ante. Sed elit turpis, tristique varius tincidunt vitae, dapibus a lectus. Nulla eleifend eget libero sit amet mollis. Proin nec auctor ligula. Aenean porta pretium eros. Mauris eu diam semper, sollicitudin turpis quis, laoreet est.

Mauris rhoncus purus nulla, quis dictum erat porttitor sed. Etiam vitae elementum turpis. Aliquam aliquet quis metus lacinia condimentum. Mauris vitae tincidunt diam. Proin bibendum tellus in pellentesque tincidunt. Proin fermentum sed magna et fermentum. Mauris urna sapien, malesuada vitae hendrerit sed, pellentesque ut augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Morbi fermentum leo nec interdum elementum. Aenean vestibulum quam ornare, sodales nisl non, molestie felis. Aenean ullamcorper nisl in ex sodales luctus. Nulla facilisi. Etiam fermentum metus at lectus iaculis, ut maximus ex euismod. Cras dignissim dictum purus at interdum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec et nisi vehicula, sagittis risus sit amet, venenatis augue.

Quisque at sagittis risus. Sed vitae est a sem volutpat feugiat vitae non massa. Quisque accumsan, libero sed convallis auctor, massa mauris imperdiet lorem, vel ultricies dolor nulla eu purus. Quisque risus diam, fermentum at dui malesuada, consequat gravida libero. In luctus purus rhoncus ipsum sagittis, quis sagittis ipsum faucibus. Sed tristique non nibh quis posuere. Nam sagittis, enim vel fermentum imperdiet, odio odio vestibulum elit, sed feugiat elit arcu in neque. Mauris id feugiat odio, at rhoncus ante. In turpis magna, condimentum non eros vitae, ultrices cursus lectus. Donec at sollicitudin odio, ac accumsan mi. Duis ultricies libero faucibus nulla lacinia faucibus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed massa quam, rhoncus eu egestas in, suscipit in purus. 
\end{document}
\end{document}


You could make it more convenient for users to look into your problem, if you would provide a compilable test document in a single code block so that users can just copy&paste it to reproduce your problem.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Leave aside that I am no latex expert I dont know I even classify as a noob. I use the sty file mainly to avoid the issues with makeat ... which I dont understand.  If you can guide me to do that I will reduce the tex+sty to only tex mwe

There are no @ in the code you showed. No need to avoid issues.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I thought I saw an answer from you but I dont see it. Do you have any suggestions or workarounds?

It was basically the same solution as later also posted by @mbert. However I came to realize that it isn't actually a solution. It just works by accident as it makes the spacing around the listing a bit smaller and thus fits the listing in the first column. It won't enable breaks into the second column. As soon as you have a longer listing or longer text, you'd have the same problem as in your question. https://i.sstatic.net/YoatgOx7.png

Hey @PustamRaut Your edit asks to change multicol(umn) to multicolor and tex to text!!

Allow your environment to take an optional argument and use the key multicols instead of placing the listing in a multicols environment.
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.95}
\definecolor{LightPGray}{gray}{0.90}
\lstnewenvironment{PYT}[1][]
      {\lstset{language=Python,
       backgroundcolor=\color{LightPGray},
       %basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
        basicstyle=\footnotesize,
        %flexiblecolumns=true,
        frame=single,
        basewidth={0.5em,0.45em},
        #1
    }}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Lorem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
\begin{PYT}[multicols=2]
>>> 1 + 2 
3
>>> () 
()
>>>(1,)
(1,)
>>> 1, 
(1,)
>>> (1,2) # Normal use
(1, 2)
>>> 1,2,  # Redundancy
(1, 2)
>>> []  # By contrast  
[]
>>> [1]
[1]
>>> [1,2]
[1, 2]
>>> [1,2]
[1,2]
1
\end{PYT}
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 

 Mauris nec dictum massa. Etiam et turpis quis dolor aliquam suscipit. Donec augue erat, interdum eget mi at, bibendum fermentum mauris. Proin ultrices risus a nulla luctus, vitae tincidunt nulla finibus. Pellentesque eget posuere mauris, sed malesuada dui. Aenean augue velit, ullamcorper vitae diam eu, rhoncus iaculis nisi. Nullam lorem velit, ullamcorper a dictum eget, fringilla ut turpis. Fusce maximus convallis consectetur. Fusce accumsan scelerisque odio, sed eleifend ex vulputate quis. Aliquam convallis non mauris non fringilla. Nulla iaculis, ipsum nec fermentum laoreet, nisi dolor lacinia turpis, sed tincidunt dui libero ac lorem. Nunc molestie felis at ullamcorper gravida. Donec elementum iaculis risus bibendum varius. Aliquam molestie, est et rutrum cursus, lacus lacus pulvinar lorem, nec dictum nulla lorem non nisl. Mauris ac tempus ex. Ut aliquet placerat dapibus.

Vestibulum tempor ultrices purus, vitae ultrices ipsum cursus a. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam non orci quis ipsum rhoncus hendrerit. Praesent sit amet ipsum eget odio vulputate tempus nec ac lacus. Nunc sit amet diam ac ipsum dignissim efficitur ac nec mauris. Donec tempor quam enim, a sollicitudin massa vulputate ut. Suspendisse faucibus mi consectetur aliquet elementum. Mauris purus mauris, lacinia vel vestibulum a, scelerisque bibendum libero. Donec congue tortor at convallis ornare. Donec sit amet vulputate nisl, non mattis sapien. Nunc venenatis ipsum ut magna fermentum sagittis.

Sed in velit vitae metus pulvinar tristique nec sed sem. Quisque semper arcu eget lectus convallis, a tempor felis fringilla. Mauris at velit orci. Aenean dui tortor, tincidunt quis volutpat non, accumsan in dui. Fusce condimentum viverra gravida. Nam ligula lacus, egestas sit amet commodo eu, tempor vel mi. Suspendisse fringilla ornare metus at mattis. Etiam in porta dolor. Pellentesque non ultrices est. Quisque tincidunt at lectus quis vulputate. In vitae metus eu metus sodales venenatis a sed neque. Pellentesque sed turpis ut mi luctus convallis. In a eleifend tortor, vel dignissim diam. Curabitur facilisis sapien et tincidunt vehicula. Aliquam fermentum leo vitae ullamcorper sodales.

Suspendisse eu lobortis urna, auctor aliquet orci. Praesent vitae dolor accumsan, maximus urna non, pulvinar risus. Ut dignissim nisi non suscipit commodo. Vestibulum finibus metus sem, nec placerat eros ullamcorper ac. Morbi congue, leo vel laoreet pharetra, lacus lorem condimentum odio, eu sagittis metus leo sed dolor. Duis ut magna non massa accumsan accumsan vitae vestibulum mi. Aenean dignissim urna sed dapibus fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Etiam suscipit, tellus ut finibus fermentum, sapien augue malesuada urna, ut aliquet quam quam vitae velit. Aliquam et sem quam.

Suspendisse tempus bibendum viverra. In lorem mauris, pulvinar nec tellus eu, cursus finibus ante. Sed elit turpis, tristique varius tincidunt vitae, dapibus a lectus. Nulla eleifend eget libero sit amet mollis. Proin nec auctor ligula. Aenean porta pretium eros. Mauris eu diam semper, sollicitudin turpis quis, laoreet est.

Mauris rhoncus purus nulla, quis dictum erat porttitor sed. Etiam vitae elementum turpis. Aliquam aliquet quis metus lacinia condimentum. Mauris vitae tincidunt diam. Proin bibendum tellus in pellentesque tincidunt. Proin fermentum sed magna et fermentum. Mauris urna sapien, malesuada vitae hendrerit sed, pellentesque ut augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Morbi fermentum leo nec interdum elementum. Aenean vestibulum quam ornare, sodales nisl non, molestie felis. Aenean ullamcorper nisl in ex sodales luctus. Nulla facilisi. Etiam fermentum metus at lectus iaculis, ut maximus ex euismod. Cras dignissim dictum purus at interdum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec et nisi vehicula, sagittis risus sit amet, venenatis augue.

Quisque at sagittis risus. Sed vitae est a sem volutpat feugiat vitae non massa. Quisque accumsan, libero sed convallis auctor, massa mauris imperdiet lorem, vel ultricies dolor nulla eu purus. Quisque risus diam, fermentum at dui malesuada, consequat gravida libero. In luctus purus rhoncus ipsum sagittis, quis sagittis ipsum faucibus. Sed tristique non nibh quis posuere. Nam sagittis, enim vel fermentum imperdiet, odio odio vestibulum elit, sed feugiat elit arcu in neque. Mauris id feugiat odio, at rhoncus ante. In turpis magna, condimentum non eros vitae, ultrices cursus lectus. Donec at sollicitudin odio, ac accumsan mi. Duis ultricies libero faucibus nulla lacinia faucibus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed massa quam, rhoncus eu egestas in, suscipit in purus. 

\end{document}

The basic problem can be seen in the following simpler example.
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\kant[1-2]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\kant[5]
\end{multicols}
\kant[6]

\end{document}

See this question and its answers. Also note that multicol warns that it may not be compatible with twocolumn mode. You don't see that warning with IEEEtran's conference option because it's not one of the "standard" classes.

Tnx. Upvoted. It's better than before but still looks unseemly (a) not aligned (b) irregular borders — Remove the backgroundcolor=\color{LightPGray} on line 11 and it will be more obvious

@Rushi I agree, it seems multicols and frame don't work well together. You can report this to the listings maintainers

But there is some solution I hope??? Latex is really quite a dragon for us non experts. I just spent 2-3 days figuring out why mathBB ℝ was not working until I found by chance that mathds works even though mathBB doesnt. Ive written a mail to jobst hoffman who is listed as the listings(!) maintainer

@Rushi Besides the listings multicols+frame issue, the issue is the interaction between IEEEtran and multicols. Even if you replace the listing with normal text between \begin{multicols}{2}...\end{multicols} you get the same column breaking behavior

By the way, it should be \mathbb, not \mathBB

Tnx the mathbb
